# Moving shape with vba based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping someone can help me out with this one.

I would like to move the flowchart terminator shape in cell H4 to a specific coordinate based on the value inputted into cell E4

Example: If I enter 0 into cell E4, I want the flowchart terminator shape to move to top = 110 and left = 918

That should put the shape directly in the center of the level image as shown below in H4

The only part I have gotten so far is how to move the shape, but I don't know how to correlate the shape movement with a change in cell E4 value

```html
Public Sub Test()

Dim oShape As Shape

Set oShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Flowchart: Terminator 123")

oShape.Top = 110
oShape.Left = 918

End Sub
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: You can use the [`Worksheet_Change()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event the sheet's code page to pull this off.

Comment: I updated my post above with the code I have so far. I just don't know how to correlate the worksheet change with the shape movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event.  You check to see if the target is E4 and then check the value of that target (Range obj).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("E4").Address Then
        If Target.Value = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Flowchart: Terminator 123").Top = 110
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Flowchart: Terminator 123").Left = 918
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sorceri. This worked perfectly and I was also able to add additional target values within the same worksheet change which is exactly what I wanted to do.